# Call blender's function bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath = output_file) through a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, import, blender, mesh

I try to import an stl mesh through a thread with bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath = output_file) but blender crashes randomly. I suppose that mesh import through a thread is not supported (thread-safe) so can you suggest a better way to implement this task?

Here is the code

```
def processData(Data, objcounter):
    SaveDataIntoSpecificFormat("File.data", Data)
    os.system("/externalexe FileData -o File%d.stl" %d objcounter)
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath = "File%d.stl" %d objcounter)

for objcounter in range(len(current_list_objs)):
    t = threading.Thread(target=processData, args=(current_list_objs[objcounter], objcounter,))
    t.start()
```

Comment: You need to remove the d after the % `File%d.stl" %d objcounter` should be `File%d.stl" % objcounter` Not certain that is a solution but throwing an exception in a thread isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the same`filename FileData` for all threads.

Make it unique using `objcounter`.